# Is it ok to connect the output of a solar controller to a fused outlet on a fuse panel?

Tags: solar-cell, fuses, solar-charge-controller, controller, power-delivery

The fuse panel is breakered to a battery and is used to power other low amp equipment.  The model is the 6 gang blue sea panel with blade type fuses.

Since the fuse panel is just a couple pieces of metal with fuse holders connecting them I didn't think it really mattered but it felt wrong routing the solar power "backwards" through the panel.

Comment: If you mean "OK" in the sense of building codes -- those vary by state or country, so check yours.  If you mean "OK" in the sense of good design practice -- it's a bit strange, but it does provide a master fuse for the rest of the system.

Comment: I'm not worried about any electrical codes, just if it's as safe as what I typically do, which is to run the battery output through a separate shortstop, and into either the fuse panel positive input or straight to the battery depending on the location and necessary cable runs. This is all for a low 30 amp system.

Comment: "codes" are all about what has been discovered to be unsafe. is this a DC system? what voltage? part of a vehicle?

Comment: DC 12 volt in a vehicle. I'm following recommended guidelines in terms of chassis grounds, wire gauge and correct breaker usage but I've found nothing to suggest this particular path for solar power is unsafe or even not recommended.